# Generating table from mysql (group) and array

Tags: php, html

I would like to generate a table with data from a database.  In one table I have data on the employee, task, date, time.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wh_task_worktime` (
`id_worktime` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_task` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_worker` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_worktime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

INSERT INTO `wh_task_worktime` (`id_worktime`, `id_task`, `id_worker`, `id_customer`, `date`, `time`) VALUES
(12, 1, 3, 1, '2013-01-18', 8),
(11, 2, 3, 2, '2013-01-18', 8),
(9, 2, 3, 2, '2013-01-16', 5),
(7, 2, 3, 2, '2013-01-15', 6),
(10, 2, 3, 2, '2013-01-13', 6),
(13, 1, 3, 1, '2013-01-16', 6),
```

Generate a table:

```
echo '<table style="width: 300px; clear:both;" class="list">';
echo '<tr class="bold">';
echo '<td style="width:100px;">Date</td>';

// Headlines tasks
$query0 = "SELECT z.name FROM ".$prefix."task_worktime cp INNER JOIN ".$prefix."task z ON cp.id_task = z.id WHERE `id_worker`= ".$id_worker." GROUP BY cp.id_task HAVING count(z.name) > 0 ";
$news0 = mysql_query($query0) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
while ($rekord0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($news0)) {
echo '<td>'.$rekord0[name].'</td>';
}
echo "</tr>";

// Here shows VERSES WITH DATE and the number of hours worked (depending on the task)
$query = "SELECT date, time, id_worktime, id_task FROM ".$prefix."task_worktime WHERE id_worker = ".$id_worker." order by date ASC";
$news1 = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$daty = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($news1)) {
$id_date = $row['date'];
if (!isset($daty[$id_date]))
$daty[$id_date] = array('date' => $row['date'], 'time' => array());

if (!empty($row['time']))
$daty[$id_date]['time'][] = array('time' => $row['time']);
}

/ / DISPLAY HOUR AND DATE
foreach ($daty as $id => $data){
echo '<tr><td>'.$data['date'].' </td>';
foreach ($data['time'] as $worktime){
echo '<td>'.$worktime['time'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($daty);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is a table with a blank verses, instead of the hole I'd like them to be zero

[image]

```
DATE        Task1   Task2
2013-01-13      6
2013-01-15      6
2013-01-16      5   6
2013-01-18      8   8
```

As an employee of the day was not it does not work on any entry in the database. Ultimately, I would like to create such a table here:

```
DATE        Task1   Task2   Task3
2013-01-01  6       0       2
2013-01-02  4       2       0
2013-01-03  0       8       0
```

Just where I scratch it doesn't have any entries in the database. The number of tasks may be different for each employee.

Thanks for any suggestions how to properly generate the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your line, where you output the worktime put a check on value like this:

```
echo '<td>'.($worktime['time']?$worktime['time']:'0').'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
echo '<td>'.(isset($worktime['time'])?$worktime['time']:'0').'</td>';
```

Comment: The array is the only time worked (no zero). See: http://awesomescreenshot.com/006u056bd

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name the columns you want returned
  FROM task_worktime cp 
  LEFT
  JOIN task z 
    ON cp.id_task = z.id 
 WHERE id_worker = '$id_worker' 
 GROUP 
    BY cp.id_task 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

?

And note that used this way, GROUP BY can give unexpected results.

Comment: You're right, corrected, but unfortunately it does not affect the generation of the table.